# Secure Public facing rest api

Tags: java, spring, rest, authentication, cookies

I am working on a public facing web service. Authentication is done by a third party and we don't have any control over it. When the user come to my page I can manually trigger the authentication process by sending the request to the third party url which in turn sends me the response suggesting if the request is valid or not. If its valid I can set up some values in cookie which I can use later to send the user information. 
The ask is to expose one web service that can check if the request is not tampered and if the user is authenticated. If its authenticated then the requested user info belongs to the same user who is asking the information.

If I just use the cookie information then its not secure and anyone can change it and can have access to other user data so I am assuming there should be some kind of token authentication or key sharing for encryption/decryption but I can be totally wrong :)

**If the application (server/url) is authorized to access the application.
User X should only have access to User X data and not user Y data.**

I am using Spring web services for web service. 
Most of the examples I came across  use login form in consideration where the user fills in his user id/pwd which is not feasible in my case.

I am stuck at this point of time. Any pointers are appreciated.
Any reference links are also welcome.

Comment: Are you using CAS for authentication? Look at spring security, and if you are using CAS, spring security with CAS

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [JWT](http://jwt.io/) (JSON Web Tokens); I think that's what you are looking for, although I'm not sure if the other party would be flexible enough on this one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Will look into it